# Migrating Kettle Files to a Repository

Tags: repository, etl, pentaho, kettle

Currently we are managing our Kettle transformation (ktr) and job (kjb) files in a local file system as XML files.  We would like to start using a Kettle repository.  I am familiar with starting from scratch with a repository, but I have never migrated hundreds of ktr/kjb files from a local file system into a repository.  Is there a utility or tool (third party, even) that facilitates a batch import from files to repository in Kettle (PDI, Pentaho Data Integration)?

We are using versoin 4.2.1

Comment: It looks like a feature was introduced in version 4.2 that will accomplish what I am trying to do: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Import+User+Documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 4.3 version comes with a sample for this case:

```
samples/Repository Import.ktr
```